# Can I integrate git local with apache localhost?

Tags: git, apache, ubuntu, gitlab

Is it possible to integrate git local with apache localhost on ubuntu?

So when I do a pull from git host. I can automatically see the updated code in my browser on apache localhost?

Should i serve apache localhost from `/home/git_repo/` or should i move my git_repo to `/var/www/` ?

I've had a look on Google and I can't seem to find anything... I've also asked around in some online forums but haven't been able to get an answer.

It seems like a relatively simple thing to do.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you wanting to do? Let's forget about apache for now. I assume you want to see some git stuff in your browser? Is that right? So if you open the browser, what do you want to enter as the URL and what do you want to see?

Comment: thanks Code-Apprentice. Sorry for not explaining myself properly. I basically don't want to have to do a pull from git host to ```/home/git_repo/``` and then do a 

```cp -R /home/git_repo/ /var/www/mysite/```

I want to be able to do a ```git pull origin master``` in ```/var/www/``` so i can see the pull in my browser straight away. I work mostly on WordPress btw. Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

so basically i have two directories...

/home/dara/git_repo/mysite_git/

and

/var/www/mysite/

when i take a pull from main i just do a...

```
cd /home/dara/git_repo/mysite_git/
git pull origin main
```

then, when i want to work on mysite on localhost. I copy the all the files from mysite_git to /var/www/mysite/. Making sure to leave out the wp-config.php file and the really-simple-ssl wordpress plugin.

```
rsync -av --progress /home/dara/git_repos/haha_git/ /var/www/mysite/ --exclude wp-config.php --exclude wp-content/plugins/really-simple-ssl
```

Replacing /var/www/mysite/ with your localhost root folder. I also have wp-config.php listed in .git/info/exclude

Maybe there's a better way of doing this. But if there is I haven't found it.